# Take a snapshot for current Android Activity?

Tags: android

I need in my project to make a snapshot for current activity (whole main layout) in Android, I attempt many ways but always I get error which "**open failed eacces (permission denied) at cretenewFile()**" My code like this:

```
public void TakeSnapshoot(){
        mainlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = mainlayout.getDrawingCache();

        String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/SaveCapture";
       File myPath = new File(extr);

        if (!myPath.exists()) {
            boolean result = myPath.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(this, result + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        myPath = new File(extr, getString(R.string.app_name) + ".jpg");

        Toast.makeText(this, myPath.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);

            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
                    "Screen", "screen");


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e("Error", e + "");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e("Error", e + "");
        }

}
```

The AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="SOA.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- For android different screen sizes -->
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    /> ...
```

after take a snapshot then I can print what I want!?  I thought this way is best way to print current activity in android?! 
Please any idea or help will be appreciated !

Comment: have you added permission for write access?

Comment: yes I do it, but still I have the same problem, I don't know why?! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function will give you a bit map of current view.

```
Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    v.getRootView().measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().width,
                    MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().height,
                    MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    // v.getp
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: But please, I need to take a snapshot for all data in ListView Can I? by using your function?  Thanks anyway ...

Comment: this function will give you a screenshot of the full screen. so whatever is on the screen you will get it capture.

Comment: I know that! but for the list view it contain scroll view so there are data will not appear in screenshot! ,,,

Comment: Oh! you can not get that because list view populate only those views which are visible on the screen.you can not get a snapshot of a view which is not created.

Comment: Thanks!  I will search for another solution ,, I wondered to use PDF functions to get all List view data! then I can print them! ...

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest file.

Hope this helps.